# How to find the rectangle center point (origin position)?

Tags: geometry, rectangles

If I have a rectangle and I try to rotate it, how to find the rectangle center point (origin position)?
I know these $3$ corners of the rectangle:

- left top: $(0,5)$
- left bottom: $(0,0)$
- right top: $(5,5)$

Comment: I wish, I had a picture of it here.  ;-)

Comment: @user1775888, won't $(5,5)$ be right top?

Comment: oh yes, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that the centre $(h,k)$ of a rectangle is the midpoint of the diagonals:

$h=\frac{0+5}2, k=\frac{5+0}2 $

---

Alternatively, use the fact the centre $(h,k)$ of a rectangle is  equidistant from the corners, so that $$(h-0)^2+(k-0)^2=(h-0)^2+(k-5)^2=(h-5)^2+(k-5)^2$$

Use the 1st two to get $h$ and the last two to get $k.$

Comment: @user1775888, please find the clues if they are sufficient

Comment: Thanks for reply, I knew the theory you mention 'centre of a rectangle is equidistant from the corners' from google, but I can't figure how trans to the function you answer before, `(h−0)2+(k−0)2=(h−0)2+(k−5)2=(h−5)2+(k−5)2` that's why I asking here. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Or May be the simplest one: where the two line joining the midpoints of opposite sides intersects.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason the question is posed with three points. It's to allow for the fact that the  rectangle may be at an angle to the axes. In the OP, it happens to be in line with the axes.

The key is to prove that for all rectangles, the mid points of the diagonals are coincidental at the centre of the rectangle and that you can therefore ignore the third point and instead concentrate on the bottom left and top right points in isolation.